# How to replace everything that is NOT equal to string x in string y Python?

Tags: python, string

Lets say I have two strings:

```
x = "String"
y = "This is a String. Strings are made up of text, not string."
```

I want to replace everything in string y that does not equal string x with something else, so something like this:

```
>>> print(y.replace(~x, ""))
StringString
```

How would I do that?

EDIT: Fixed some confusing , uneeded things

Comment: Or you could just count the number of times `String`  appears in `y`, and generate a new string saying `String` that many times

Comment: Wouldn't the expected result be `, String, String, `? Why does the first bit of text get omitted?

Comment: Why is the expected result not `",,,,,,,,,,String,,String,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"`? You could say that `T` is not equal to x, so it is replaced by `,`. And `h` is not equal to x, so it is replaced by `,`. Etc. (I know this sounds ridiculous but I want to make it clear that you could specify more precisely what you mean by "everything that is not equal to x".)

Comment: @EricRaisin I think my solution is a better answer for you edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```py
  x * y.count(x)
```

Answer to obtain `", String, String, "` like before the question was edited:

```py
def inv_replace(x, y, delim=", "):
  pre = delim if y.index(x) else ""
  post = delim if y.rindex(x) + len(x) != len(y) else ""
  return pre + delim.join([x] * y.count(x)) + post
```

Comment: This is really good! (I honestly didn't know about it before)

Comment: This is by far the easiest answer I've come by! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to replace the words in the string, you can simply check each word and replace it if it isn't equal to the word you want to protect, like this:

```py
s = "foo bar foobar bar foocar foo"
sl = s.split(" ") #put all words in a list
for i in range(len(sl)):
  word = sl[i]
  if not word == "bar":
    sl[i] = "newtext" #make the word into "newtext", and replace it in the list
s = sl.join(" ") #put the words back in the string
```

Output:

```
>>> "newtext bar newtext bar newtext newtext"
```